# How to define value of function type alias without repeating the types?

Tags: scala

Given the function type alias:

```
type Func = (Int, Double) => String
```

and I want to define one such function, one way of doing it would be

```
val foo: Func = (n: Int, d: Double) => n.toString + " " + d.toString
```

However I am trying to understand if there is a less verbose way akin to accessing a tuple, without naming the arguments explicitly again when the type is known, such as (hypothetically)

```
val foo: Func = _1.toString + " " + _2.toString
```

Is there anything at all that accomplishes this? It would save me an immense amount of typing and would make my code much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use ordinary shorthand notation which iterates through the parameters in order:

```
val foo: Func = _ + " " + _
```

If that is not general enough, you need only name the parameters, not supply their types again:

```
val foo: Func = (x,y) => (x + (x + y*y)).toString
```

Comment: The ordinary shorthand works in the simple example I gave (maybe I should have thought up something more complex) but is not enough generally. But your second suggestion does save a bit of typing and I wasn't aware of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

```
val foo: Func = _.toString + " " + _.toString
```

You have to realize that the arguments `n` and `d` don't form a `Tuple`, but are independent. To be a tuple, the type should have been `((Int, Double)) => String` , note the additional parenthesis.

Comment: That's right, they are not a tuple. I'd mentioned the tuple simply to give an example of one of the syntaxes used by Scala to access unnamed values and suggest whether something of the kind may exist. Thank you for the answer!